# Replace values in two data frames with null if difference is below zero

Tags: r

I would like to set values in two data frames and in specific columns to null if when subtracted result in negative values.

For example if I have df1 and df2 like below:

```
df1 <- cbind(v1=c(3,6,4,8,4), v2=c(8,6,7,3,5), v3=c(7,6,8,5,8))
df2 <- cbind(v1=c(5,3,8,7,9), v2=c(1,1,7,4,5), v3=c(7,1,2,5,3))
```

And I have a vector of column names:

```
v <- c('v1', 'v3')
```

Using the result of the following subtraction:

```
df2[,v]-df1[,v] < 0

v1    v3
FALSE FALSE
TRUE  TRUE
FALSE  TRUE
TRUE FALSE
FALSE  TRUE
```

I would like to set values in both df1 and df2 to null if they are true.

Expected result:

df1:

```
v1    v2    v3
3     8     7
NA    6     NA
4     7     NA
NA    3     5
4     5     NA
```

df2:

```
v1    v2    v3
5     1     7
NA    1     NA
8     7     NA
NA    4     5
9     5     NA
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the expected output and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you provided:

```
df1 <- cbind(v1=c(3,6,4,8,4), v2=c(8,6,7,3,5), v3=c(7,6,8,5,8))
df2 <- cbind(v1=c(5,3,8,7,9), v2=c(1,1,7,4,5), v3=c(7,1,2,5,3))
v <- c('v1', 'v3')
```

Now save the result from `df2[,v] - df1[,v]` in `df3`

```
# intermediate step:
df3 <- df2[,v]-df1[,v]
```

Replace all positive values in `df3` with a `0` (or any value for that matter)

```
df3[df3 > 0] <- 0
df3
```

**Edit:**

When you wish to replace the values in `df1` and `df2`, use the `df3 > 0` to index them:

```
df1[df3 > 0] <- 0     # or some other value than 0
df2[df3 > 0] <- 0     # or some other value than 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I get the following:

```
df1 <- cbind(v1=c(3,6,4,8,4), v2=c(8,6,7,3,5), v3=c(7,6,8,5,8))
df2 <- cbind(v1=c(5,3,8,7,9), v2=c(1,1,7,4,5), v3=c(7,1,2,5,3))
v <- c('v1', 'v3')

ifelse(df2[,v] - df1[,v]<0,NA,df2[,v]-df1[,v])
```

Where the ifelse function is used as follows ... if the subtraction is less than 0, the answer is NA, if not (else) it is the result of the subtraction.  This code results in,

```
     v1 v3
[1,]  2  0
[2,] NA NA
[3,]  4 NA
[4,] NA  0
[5,]  5 NA
```

Comment: This answer no longer correlates with the question you asked because you edited your question such that it asked something completely different from your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by computing the difference for the subset v and using the result to replace subset v values in df1 and df2:

```
df3 <- df1[,v]-df2[,v]
df1[,v][df3<0] <- NA
df2[,v][df3<0] <- NA
```